# Better way to create associative array from Doctrine resultset

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm often making simple loops like this to map a single value from a Doctrine resultset to a id->value mapped array:

```
            $rows = $this->em->getRepository(Tag::class)->findAll();
            $result = [];
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $result[$row->getId()] = $row->getName();
            }
```

I remember seeing an example of a simpler way to do this, with an array function like array_map maybe..but can't figure it out. Anyone got a way to do this with less code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is doctrine's [INDEX_BY](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#using-index-by)

> By default a result is incremented by numerical keys starting with 0.
> However with INDEX BY you can specify any other column to be the key
> of your result, it really only makes sense with primary or unique
> fields though

```
$query = $this->em->getRepository(Tag::class)
                  ->createQueryBuilder('t')
                  ->indexBy('t', 't.id');
$result = $query
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```

Comment: @Oli you can make it simpler by using second params of **public function createQueryBuilder($alias, $indexBy = null)**

Comment: `$query = $this->em->getRepository(Tag::class)->createQueryBuilder('t', 't.id')`